# Need method to return XElement instead of byte[]

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, xelement

I have the following method that I need to return an `XElement`.  The problem is that can't figure out how to convert a `byte[]` into an `XElement`.

```
public XElement ServiceCallForNewMadidPlantReport()
{
    var kpiReportClient = new ReportExecutionService();
    kpiReportClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("*****");
    kpiReportClient.Url = endPoint.ToString();

    //render arguments 
    byte[]result = null;
    string reportSickTimePlants = "/Human Resources/KPI POW/Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg"; //report path
    string format = "XML";
    string historyID = null;
    string devInfo = "";

    //prepare report parameter
    ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[4];
    parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[0].Name = "Location";
    parameters[0].Value = "4"; //New Madrid
    parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[1].Name = "UnCode";
    parameters[1].Value = "Non-Union";
    parameters[2] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[2].Name = "StartDate";
    parameters[2].Value = "01/01/2006";
    parameters[3] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[3].Name = "EndDate";
    parameters[3].Value = "08/08/2012";

    string encoding;
    string mimeType;
    string extension;
    Warning[] warnings = null;            
    string[] streamIDs;

    ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
    ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
    kpiReportClient.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

    var trustedUserHeader = new TrustedUserHeader();            

    execInfo = kpiReportClient.LoadReport(reportSickTimePlants, historyID);

    kpiReportClient.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

    String SessionId = kpiReportClient.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

    Console.WriteLine("SessionID: {0}", kpiReportClient.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID);

    try
    {
        result = kpiReportClient.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        execInfo = kpiReportClient.GetExecutionInfo();
    }
    catch (SoapException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml);
    }
    try
    {
        FileStream sickTimReportForPlants = File.Create("SickTimeNonRepEmpReport.xml", result.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("File created.");
        Console.WriteLine(sickTimReportForPlants);
        sickTimReportForPlants.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Result written to the file.");                
        sickTimReportForPlants.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return ? (must be XElement)
}
```

Here is what I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
result = kpiReportClient.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
Console.WriteLine(result);
string resultString  = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
var nonRepSickReportForNM = XElement.Parse(resultString);
```

This gives me the following error:

> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
>   position 1.

I've tried several other ways as well but no matter what I do I get the same error.  Here is what the xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Report xsi:schemaLocation="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg http://gonzo/ReportServer?%2fHuman+Resources%2fKPI+POW%2fKpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg&amp;rs%3aFormat=XML&amp;rc%3aSchema=True" Name="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg" Location="New Madrid" Textbox84="KPI SICK / FMLA 1/1/2006 12:00:00 AM - 8/8/2012 12:00:00 AM" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg"><Tablix1><Textbox13><Textbox3><Textbox15 /></Textbox3></Textbox13><Category_Collection><Category Category1="FMLA"><represented1_Collection><represented1 represented11="Non-Union"><QTR_Collection><QTR QTR1="1" Textbox27="1787" /><QTR QTR1="2" Textbox27="988.75" /><QTR QTR1="3" Textbox27="1577.75" /><QTR QTR1="4" Textbox27="2133.25" /></QTR_Collection></represented1></represented1_Collection></Category><Category Category1="Sick"><represented1_Collection><represented1 represented11="Non-Union"><QTR_Collection><QTR QTR1="1" Textbox27="5407.5" /><QTR QTR1="2" Textbox27="4051.75" /><QTR QTR1="3" Textbox27="3928" /><QTR QTR1="4" Textbox27="4204.75" /></QTR_Collection></represented1></represented1_Collection></Category></Category_Collection></Tablix1></Report>
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:

after doing the following:

```
string resultFromBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
return XDocument.Parse(resultFromBytes).Root;
```

I still get the same error message but here is my xml from resultFromBytes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Report xsi:schemaLocation="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg http://gonzo/ReportServer?%2fHuman+Resources%2fKPI+POW%2fKpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg&amp;rs%3aFormat=XML&amp;rc%3aSchema=True" Name="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg" Location="New Madrid" Textbox84="KPI SICK / FMLA 1/1/2006 12:00:00 AM - 8/8/2012 12:00:00 AM" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg"><Tablix1><Textbox13><Textbox3><Textbox15 /></Textbox3></Textbox13><Category_Collection><Category Category1="FMLA"><represented1_Collection><represented1 represented11="Non-Union"><QTR_Collection><QTR QTR1="1" Textbox27="1787" /><QTR QTR1="2" Textbox27="988.75" /><QTR QTR1="3" Textbox27="1577.75" /><QTR QTR1="4" Textbox27="2133.25" /></QTR_Collection></represented1></represented1_Collection></Category><Category Category1="Sick"><represented1_Collection><represented1 represented11="Non-Union"><QTR_Collection><QTR QTR1="1" Textbox27="5407.5" /><QTR QTR1="2" Textbox27="4051.75" /><QTR QTR1="3" Textbox27="3928" /><QTR QTR1="4" Textbox27="4204.75" /></QTR_Collection></represented1></represented1_Collection></Category></Category_Collection></Tablix1></Report>
```

EDIT:

After doing this:

```
string resultFromBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"xsi:schemaLocation="".+""");
string strippedxml = regex.Replace(resultFromBytes, "");
return XDocument.Parse(strippedxml).Root;
```

I get the same failure.  This is what the strippedxml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Report  /></QTR_Collection></represented1></represented1_Collection></Category></Category_Collection></Tablix1></Report>
```

EDIT:

Tried this and xml looks much better but still fails with same error:

```
string resultFromBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"xsi:schemaLocation="".+""");
string strippedxml = regex.Replace(resultFromBytes, "");
return XDocument.Parse(strippedxml).Root;
```

here's what the xml from strippedxml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Report  Name="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg" Location="New Madrid" Textbox84="KPI SICK / FMLA 1/1/2006 12:00:00 AM - 8/8/2012 12:00:00 AM" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Kpi_Fmla_Summarized_Plants_Prg"><Tablix1><Textbox13><Textbox3><Textbox15 /></Textbox3></Textbox13><Category_Collection><Category Category1="FMLA"><represented1_Collection><represented1 represented11="Non-Union"><QTR_Collection><QTR QTR1="1" Textbox27="1787" /><QTR QTR1="2" Textbox27="988.75" /><QTR QTR1="3" Textbox27="1577.75" /><QTR QTR1="4" Textbox27="2133.25" /></QTR_Collection></represented1></represented1_Collection></Category><Category Category1="Sick"><represented1_Collection><represented1 represented11="Non-Union"><QTR_Collection><QTR QTR1="1" Textbox27="5407.5" /><QTR QTR1="2" Textbox27="4051.75" /><QTR QTR1="3" Textbox27="3928" /><QTR QTR1="4" Textbox27="4204.75" /></QTR_Collection></represented1></represented1_Collection></Category></Category_Collection></Tablix1></Report>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parse it as base-64? Just try `XElement.Parse(result)`

Comment: @JohnSaunders That was the very first thing I tried to do.  XElement.Parse takes a string and result was a byte[] type so it gave me an error.  I tried to make result a string[] instead of a byte[] but that didn't work if I understand the MSDN, ReportExecutionService.Render() has to be a byte[]

Comment: @JohnSaunders I misspoke.  I first tried using XElement.Parse(result) but it wouldn't take it because it had to be a string.  Then I tried  XElement.Parse(result.ToString()) and I received the same error I received with all the others.  I tried to parse it as a base 64 because when I googled it that was a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: I have no idea why you would get this error from `XDocument.Parse(resultBytes)`. XMLSpy sees nothing wrong with that XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the answer.  I was trying to converti it from a byte[] to an XElement.  Instead, I converted it into a stream and THEN into the Xelement.  Like this:

```
result = kpiReportClient.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
Console.WriteLine(result);
result = kpiReportClient.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
Stream resStream = new MemoryStream(result);
var nonRepSickReportForNM = XElement.Load(resStream);
return nonRepSickReportForNM
```

I can't take credit for it though.  My boss figured it out.

Comment: You should use `using (Stream resStream = new MemoryStream(result)){return XElement.Load(resStream);}`. That will ensure that the stream is cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the line of this: (fixed the namespace trouble)

```
string resultFromBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);

var nt = new NameTable();
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
nsmgr.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "urn:samples"); //default namespace
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "urn:samples2"); // xsi fix

var context = new XmlParserContext(nt, nsmgr,null,  XmlSpace.None);

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;

var xrdr= XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), settings, context);
return XDocument.Load(xrdr).Root;
```

Comment: XDocument.Parse takes a string so I did "return XDocument.Parse(result.ToString()).Root;" but received the same error

Comment: I missed that result was a byte[] array. I assume it does contain an UTF8Encoded string...

Comment: Yes it does contain an UTF8Encoded string.  Unfortunately I get the same error.  There must be something wrong with my xml.  I just don't know enough about it to see what it is.

Comment: The schemaLocation in the root node is the culprit

Comment: added a regex for now to see if this is a quick fix

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work.  I still have the same error.  I will continue to investigate.

Comment: The xml looks much better but still fails with the same problem

Comment: There should be no need to "clean up" the XML. I don't know why anyone would even consider that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders you are so correct... I'm more than happy to get rid of it.